# Is there a way to copy unescaped text variable values in VSC?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, escaping, watch

What I want is so simple. In Visual Studio Code, I want to copy the value of a text variable from the Watch window into memory.

I understand that, in the watch window, the text is escaped to put everything on one line. In other words,

```
Hello
world
```

is displayed as `Hello\nworld` in the Watch window. That makes sense.

But when I right-click on a string variable in the Watch window and select "Copy Value", I expect the copied value to be

```
Hello
world
```

not
`'Hello\nworld'`

Is there a way to do this in VSC (without the tedious need to search and replace for escape characters)?

(If you're as stumped as me, Upvote in solidarity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but here goes:

This may depend on which debugger you are using, the below works in node/JavaScript.

Go to the Debug Console tab, and type the var name or expression at the prompt.

The debugger outputs the value, and you can select and copy it from there.

[image]

Comment: That's a great idea, @mesh.

I'd prefer it without the quotes but this approach will get me a long way to where I need to be. The text is probably still going to have weird backticks and such to cater for single-quote, for example - but this is an improvement for sure.